# Imageview with toast

Tags: android, image, imageview, toast

I have a project. But when I click the image, it redirects me to img_3.I want to when I click to:

```
 img_1 and toast 1
 img_2 and toast 2
 img_3 and toast 3
```

And to keep it on the same image.

please tell me, how can i write a code?

This is code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView view;
    Random r;
    Button button;
    Integer[] images= {
            R.drawable.img_1,
            R.drawable.img_2,
            R.drawable.img_3,
    };

    int pickedImage = 0,lastPicked = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        r = new Random();
        view = (ImageView)findViewById(idImageView);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                do {
                    pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);
                } while (pickedImage == lastPicked);

                lastPicked = pickedImage;

                view.setImageResource(images[pickedImage]);


            }

        });
        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ptak 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_1);

                toast1.show();

            }
        });

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ptak 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_2);
                toast2.show();

            }
        });

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ptak 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_3);
                toast3.show();

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: question is not clear ? what exactly you want to do ? If you click image_1, toast_1 should display. Is this what you want?

Comment: I want, when i click to img_1,toast 1 and doesn´t direct to img_3,toast 3

Answer (score 2):

Because you are setting OnClick Listener multiple times on single view it will override all other listeners to the last one. So thats the reason toast-3 is showing eveytime.

Instead you call do something like this :

No need to make it complex with do while loop :

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);

            view.setImageResource(images[pickedImage]);


        }

    });
```

no need to set view.setImageResource after the toast.

```
view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                switch (pickedImage) {
                    case 0:
                        Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ptak 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        toast1.show();

                        break;
                    case 1:
                        Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ptak 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        toast2.show();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ptak 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

                        toast3.show();
                        break;

                }

            }
        });
```

This code is working perfectly (Tested)

Clicking on button will take any random image out of 3.

Clicking on Image will give the toast for that Image. (Like Image-1 to Toast-1)

Comment: No, when you click the image. You directed to next image and after show toast. Img_1 -> img_2 And toast 2

Comment: Pardon I am not able to understand what you are trying to convey. you want something like while clicking on Img_1  it should change to img_2 and show toast img_2 or you want clicking on Img_1 should show just Toast_1

Comment: I want click to img1 And show toast 1. Now, when i click to img1 change img2 And show  toast 2

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Will it work after you've modified the random generator code?

Comment: Yes . You can test it and if it is what you wanted than you can accept it.

Comment: Ok, I must delete a part do{}?

Comment: I have problem, when I turn around(widht) a display the image  disseapear.

Comment: I think your question has been answered. You can ask your additional questions seperately.

Comment: I have same project, but bigger and doesn´t work.  This is my code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K6h2CLTWqSbONU_y37NGnivjXp8McZsQ4NKVtGK0bIU/edit?usp=sharing                                                                  Why does it not work? Same problem:mg_1 it should change to img_2 and show toast img_2(for example)

Answer (score 1):

Use custom Toast like this

```
    Toast toast = new Toast(this);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER,100,100);
    toast.setView(view);
```

Comment: But in  view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() doesn´t write (this)

Comment: Do `MainActivity.this` as you need the Context. If you do `this` inside the `OnClickListener`, `this` references the listener itself.

Answer (score 0):

Dont add click listener three time. It will always take the last listener.  Try like below,

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            r = new Random();
            view = (ImageView)findViewById(idImageView);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    do {
                        pickedImage = r.nextInt(images.length);
                    } while (pickedImage == lastPicked);

                    lastPicked = pickedImage;

                    view.setImageResource(images[pickedImage]);


                }

            });
            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if(lastPick == 0){
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ptak 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_1);

                    toast1.show();
                 }else if(lastPick ==1){
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ptak 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_2);
                    toast2.show();
                 }else if(lastPick ==2){
                    Toast toast3 = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"ptak 3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    view.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_3);
                    toast3.show();
                  }

                }
            });



        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: If this solves your problem. Please do accept my answer. :)

Comment: But always directed(jumped) to next image

Comment: Means, each time you click the button its going to next image ?

Comment: No, when you click the image. You directed to next image and after show toast. Img_1 -> img_2 And toast 2

Comment: I have same project, but bigger and doesn´t work. This is my code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1K6h2CLTWqSbONU_y37NGnivjXp8McZsQ4NKVtGK0bIU/edit?usp=sharing  Why does it not work? Same problem:mg_1 it should change to img_2 and show toast img_2(for example)